# Ejabberd recommended linux libraries for ODBC connection with Ms SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ejabberd

I am working with Ejabberd and MSSQL server as data store in Linux environment.

**What are the ODBC libraries recommended for linux environment to connect Mssql for latest version of Ejabberd.**

Currently using older version of Ejabberd with FreeTDS, Unix ODBC libraries for MSSQL connection.

Comment: Microsoft now has a supported ODBC driver for Linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks David. @ejabberd team is there any inbuilt config support of Microsoft ODBC library with linux binaries..

Comment: Hello @David, when I have checking the yum list msodbcsql17 I got no matching packages to list. Tried with msodbcsql getting 13.0.1.0-1. please let me know if this msodbcsql is the older version of ODBC driver?

Comment: The doc for installing msodbcsql17 on distros that use yum is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#redhat17

Comment: great question - I ended up here looking for the same answer - I setup the ms provided odbc driver and have verified that isql does work with the entry in odbc - I havnt figured out how to hook it up to ejabberd yet.,.